# Double trouble - When slitherloops collide

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction, slitherlink

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #13: Variety Slitherlinks](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/monthly-topic-challenge-13-variety-slitherlinks).</sub>

---

What happens when you're working on a couple of puzzles for the Monthly Topic Challenge and try to merge them?

Well, in my case it all went quite smoothly until Penpa gave me a very strange error message -  *"Widening their six-sided cat limousines"* - and deleted the solution, leaving just the puzzle.

So if anyone could work out what my intended solution was, and explain that weird error message, I'd be really grateful.

Standard(ish) slitherlink rules:

- Draw <strike>a single</strike> **two**, non-**self-**intersecting loop**s** that only consists of horizontal and vertical segments between the dots.
- Numbers inside a cell indicate how many of the edges of that cell are part of <strike>the</strike>**that** loop.
- **Loops may cross straight over at an intersection, but may not follow the same edge, nor meet when they turn.**
  [image]

[image]

[Penpa solving link](https://tinyurl.com/2c25e65e)

I'm expecting a completed slitherlink grid, preferably with solve path; and a single twelve letter word.

Comment: I have to ask - is that cryptic clue very relevant to the solution?

Comment: Also, how do you get different colored X's? I can only get the green one.

Comment: What cryptic clue? Why not try solving the puzzle first and see what you find.

Comment: Penpa only has one colour for X.

Comment: And before anyone asks, no I don't know whether it's the felines or the automobiles that are hexagonal.

Comment: Quick question: can the loops overlap?

Comment: Am I the only one to wonder why there are grey cells?

Comment: Looks like there's a contradiction in the bottom-left corner. Is the grey-blue 2 correct? Are the grey cells red herrings?

Comment: Is the phrase rot13(A GUR V RNGF) relevant or am I way off?

Comment: @newQOpenWid There is no contradiction that I can see in the bottom left.

Comment: @caPNCApn You're way off

Comment: @fljx Gotcha. Does the Penpa tell you when you solved the loops?

Comment: No, I didn't enable the solver, as Penpa doesn't support two loops like this (unless you use the double lines, which are also green and make an ugly mess of the grid).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*What happens when you're working on a couple of puzzles for the Monthly Topic Challenge and try to merge them?*

> **INTERSECTION**

The solved loops

> [image]

Then we

> put that very strange error message in the gray boxes and read the off the letters in cells with lines on all four sides
>  [image]

Comment: Unrelated to the puzzle itself, but how do I stop abusing bifurcating and still get the answer? I use bifurcating way too much and it's kind of troubling me.

Comment: Well, the usual way to solve logic puzzles is to list (or pencil mark) things that must be true, things that cannot be true, and then try to make those things interact with each other, eventually yielding positive facts you can put in the grid. In slitherlink, some of the usual (possibly non-obvious) considerations are "if this square is inside the loop, how does it connect to all the other inside squares", "(how) can the loop (not) pass through this intersection" and "many routes are blocked for some reason; how can I make the loop visit that area at all". Bifurcation feels like giving up.

Comment: @newQOpenWid none of my recent puzzles should require any bifurcation/guesswork. I suspect you either: A) are failing to spot where the next logical move is (can easily happen when a puzzle reaches a bottleneck and there's only a single non-obvious "next move") or B) you've not aware of (or have never worked out for yourself) some less-used or harder to spot patterns, so don't have them in your puzzle solving "toolkit".